# Don't understand when a ROR View will/will not have a param for a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am having difficulty understanding how to cause a View in ROR4 to have a param for a model. It shows up when I try to use strong parameters in a controller, specifically:

```
 def model1_params
   params.require(:model1).permit(:attr1,attr2)
 end
```

Sometimes it works.  Sometimes I get "param not found: model1"

My understanding is that it fails (when it does) because the web page being submitted doesn't have any param called "model1" and that it works (when it does) because something I have done has caused the web page submission to have this param.  In the latter case, the param is a hash representing the fields of the model, with members for attr1, attr2, etc.

Does it work when I use "form_for" (which specifies a model) but not the other kind of form call, which is not tied to a model?

Note: I am writing because I've had this problem for several weeks with no progress.  I have searched the Rails doc and lots of instructional examples on the web but with no luck.  I know I'm being dense, but so far I've not found a real API reference document, nor a real API programmer's guide that covers strong parameters.

I've found lots of examples on strong parameters but none of them clearly explain how it works, that would let me figure out on my own what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Yes, it would work with `form_for` with a symbol as an argument rather than an ActiveRecord object. Perhaps it might be clearer if you explained what exactly are the circumstances that are causing your `param[:model1]` not to exist?

Comment: Thanks, Depa. I will look into changing to form_for.  If I still have a problem I will get back with the circumstances, as you suggested.  Note: I'm copying an example from "Learning Rails 3", St. Laurent, Dumbill, & Gruber (O'Reilly).  But I am having to modify some samples because I am using Rails 4.  For some reason, the book switches to form_tag instead of form_for for this controller/view. (Maybe form_for is not good for many-many?) Currently  trying to add actions to allow student to enroll in course, list courses for a student, list students for a course, etc.

Comment: With help from Depa and Miotsu, I now understand how Rails parameters work, and I was able to fix the problem.  Thanks!  Thanks also to my (ruthless, but talented) editors...I am learning StackOverflow mechanics (and culture) with your assistance.  (You may want to cut that last; I'm probably just trying to get on your good side).

Answer (score 0):

Say your controller's method is associated to a route `model1_controller_method_path`.
Your method can be called from a link in a view, and if the `model1` parameter is not present, yes, you will get a 'param not found' error. To avoid this, make sure to have your parameter passed from your link_to as in:

```
link_to model1_controller_method_path(:model1 => the_value_you_want)
```

Comment: Thanks much, Miotsu.  I will check this out and followup.